# I2C read error while getting data from sensor with pigpio

Tags: python, i2c

i have a Tkinter GUI and the acceleration sensor MMA8452Q. I set up the sensor that if a threshold is reached, a interrupt flag gets set and data for a specific period of time gets collected and plotted through the GUI.

Sometimes when I read the data or at any other point of using an I2C read function to read a register i get the error "I2C read failed" (when the error happens in the check_flags() method) and sometimes I get something like this:

```
interrupt 1 True
4 0 1810275105
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.../tkinter/mix/mix_interrupt.py", line 307, in check_flags
    pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, FF_MT_SRC)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 2874, in i2c_read_byte_data
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_I2CRB, handle, reg))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1011, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))
pigpio.error: 'I2C read failed'
```

Is there maybe something wrong with my code or should i could the baudrate be the fault of this problem? It doesn't happen all the time, but seemingly at random times. Just to clarify, if the error happens in the try-except-block, my data still gets plotted, but some data gets missing and the plot looks sometimes incomplete

My important code parts:

This is the thread:

```
threading.Thread(target=self.check_flags).start() #This is in the init method
```

This function runs in a thread like this and checks if self.interrupt_flag is set

```
def check_flags(self):
        while(True):
            #print("check the flags")
            if (self.interrupt_flag == True):
                pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, FF_MT_SRC)
                global scale_variable
                self.x_graph = []
                self.y1_graph = []
                self.y2_graph = []
                self.y3_graph = []
                
                a = datetime.datetime.now()
                one_time = True 
                start_time = time.time()*1000
                while(time.time()*1000-start_time) < self.timeframe:
                    try:
                        b = datetime.datetime.now()
                        delta = b-a
                        y1 = self.readACCx()
                        y2 = self.readACCy()
                        y3 = self.readACCz()
                        self.y1_graph.append(y1)
                        self.y2_graph.append(y2)
                        self.y3_graph.append(y3)
                        self.x_graph.append(delta.total_seconds()*1000)
                        if (y1 > self.threshold or y2 > self.threshold): # this is for catching the whole movement if its longer than the set timeframe
                            self.timeframe += 5          
                    except pigpio.error as e:
                        print("error:", e)
                self.save_data()
                self.plot_data()
                self.interrupt_flag = False
```

This is one of the functions i use to read sensor data. The other two are almost identical

```
def readACCx(self): #reads x axis value 12 bit
        global scale_variable
        comp_acc_x2 = pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, OUT_X_MSB)
        comp_acc_x1 = pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, OUT_X_LSB)
        acc_combined = ((comp_acc_x2 << 8) | comp_acc_x1) >>4
        if acc_combined < 2048:
            acc_combined = acc_combined*scale_variable
            return acc_combined
        else:
            acc_combined = acc_combined - 4096
            acc_combined = acc_combined*scale_variable
            return acc_combined
```

This is my interrupt routine:

```
def my_callback1(self, gpio, level, tick): #first interrupt function
        self.interrupt_flag = True
        print("interrupt 1", self.interrupt_flag)
        
        print(gpio, level, tick)
```

EDIT (ALMOST PERFECT) WORKING CODE:

```
protect = threading.Lock() # this is outside of any class at the top

def check_flags(self): # new data capture method
        while(True):
            #print("check the flags")
            if (self.interrupt_flag == True):
                protect.acquire()
                ff_flag = pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, FF_MT_SRC)
                print("interrupt cleared", ff_flag)
                global scale_variable
                self.x_graph = []
                self.y1_graph = []
                self.y2_graph = []
                self.y3_graph = []
                
                a = datetime.datetime.now()
                one_time = True 
                start_time = time.time()*1000
                while(time.time()*1000-start_time) < self.timeframe:
                    try:
                        b = datetime.datetime.now()
                        delta = b-a
                        y1 = self.readACCx()
                        y2 = self.readACCy()
                        y3 = self.readACCz()
                        self.y1_graph.append(y1)
                        self.y2_graph.append(y2)
                        self.y3_graph.append(y3)
                        self.x_graph.append(delta.total_seconds()*1000)
                        if (y1 > self.threshold or y2 > self.threshold):
                            self.timeframe += 5
                    except pigpio.error as e:
                        print("error:", e)
                self.save_data()
                self.plot_data()
                self.interrupt_flag = False
                self.timeframe = self.config.getint('setting', 'timeframe')
                print("scale_variable: ", scale_variable)
                protect.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your traceback doesn't match your code.  The traceback shows the `i2c_read_byte_data` result not being saved anywhere.  The I2C clock must be right, otherwise you'd get nothing at all.

The problem is probably synchronization.  When you said "interrupt", that raised a red flag.  If your interrupt handler tries to do an I2C operation while your mainline code is also doing one, the two will clash, especially since you have to do MSB and LSB separately.  I suggest you use a `threading.Lock` to make sure your sequences aren't interrupted.

Comment: Hello, sorry i mistakenly posted code i added some debug lines to. I edited it to reflect how it looked before.

Comment: Does my callback still do I2C operations even if it just sets a variable to true? It looks like to me that i dont call any I2C method. Does the error maybe happen if another interrupt happens while the thread is in the while-loop?
Thanks for helping me, i hope we will find a solution

Comment: The traceback now says it's being called from `mix_interrupt`, not `check_flags`.  If you have multiple threads reading I2C, then you MUST protect them with a lock.

Comment: `mix_interrupt` is the python file and `check_flags` is the method in the file. How would i go about protection with a lock?

Comment: You're right about the names, sorry, my mistake.    Check here https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html and click on "Lock objects".

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I think I need to see some examples before trying my hand at this. If i understand this correctly the Interrupt is a thread and the check_flag method which also runs on a thread clash when a Interrupt happens. Even though the Interrupt doesnt get started like a thread, it still is one and should be possible to influence with `threading.Lock` ? Because I think i need to "pause" the interrupts from happening while `check_flags` method is running

Comment: Yes, that's what the lock would do.  Create `protect = threading.Lock()` as a global, then use `protect.acquire()` and `protect.release()` around your I2C sections.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I just got around to testing with the lock and pretty good. I updated my code too, if you wanna take a look. But even now i sometimes get the I2C read error. In my 8 try's it happened only 2 times which is very good, considering i used to get errors every time i shaked longer. Any thoughts on that or is it maybe something i cant influenze? The data also seems very cohesive and i cant see any clear errors in the plot

Comment: Remember that EVERY I2C access needs the lock.  That includes `readACCx`.  Also remember that you ONLY need to protect the I2C.  You can move the `protect.release()` in `check_flags` to immediately after the read.  No need to protect the other code.

Comment: But when i put the lock at the top and at the bottom it should catch every I2C read, even the `readACCx` right? I will try to move the `release` portion and report back

Comment: Yes, you're right, but that leaves things locked for a very long time.

Comment: Hey, i tried to move the release portion and on the first try i got the same error which is in my post at the top. I think i have two options, either use a `try-except-loop` like I did with the sensor data or disable this portion, because I think i really don't need to clear the interrupt. This error happens so rarely but can crash the whole code.. Anyway I will try both options and report back

Comment: Ok i just took that portion out of the code and it works nice. I might change some things up but thats something for another question. Thanks for your help :)